# Unable to connect Tableau Desktop to remote Mongo Server

Tags: mongodb, tableau-desktop

I am trying to connect a Tableau desktop to a remote MongoDB server using ODBC connector. I have followed the steps mentioned in this page https://docs.mongodb.com/bi-connector/current/connect/tableau-auth/#std-label-connect-tableau-auth
But I am getting the below error

[MySQL][ODBC 1.4(w) Driver]Can't connect to MySQL server on '13.38.33.197' (64)
Generic ODBC requires additional configuration. The driver and DSN (data source name) must be installed and configured to match the connection.
Unable to connect using the DSN named "test new". Check that the DSN exists and is a valid connection.

Please help me in resolving the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error occurs when a running mongosqld instance cannot be found. Here are the steps to follow for a successful connection to mongoDB from Tableau desktop.

1. Install mongoDB connector for BI on your machine.
2. In command prompt, navigate to mongosqld file location.
3. Use the below command to provide host and connection details
   mongosqld --mongo-uri  --auth --mongo-username  --mongo-password  --mongo-authenticationSource
4. The above command will create a live connection on localhost.
5. Create a system DSN with host/server IP as localhost or 127.0.0.1 and the same DB credentials.
6. On Tableau Desktop, select connect via Other Databases (ODBC).
7. Select the system DSN created and click on connect.